# Using back button on a HTML page to show/hide divs according to user click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below I have three divisions in HTML. I am using jquery for hiding and showing those divs according to user clicks on buttons. I also have a back button. How do I track user clicks so that I can show the division user viewed previously

```xml
<div id="signupform" style="display: block;">
    <form id="signupForm" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="floatContainer1" class="float-container mt-4">
            <label for="floatField1">E-mail Id</label>
            <input type="email" id="floatField1" data-placeholder="abc@xyz.com" required>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn-block btn-orange mt-4 p-3">Verify</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="otpform" style="display: none;" class="my-5">
    <div id="wrong_otp" class="position-absolute text-danger text-left" style="top: -30px;display: none;">
        Please enter the correct OTP
    </div>
    <form id="verify_otp" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="floatContainer2" class="float-container mt-4">
            <label for="floatField2">Verify OTP</label>
            <input type="text" id="floatField2" data-placeholder="Please Enter the 6-Digit OTP" required>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn-block btn-orange mt-4 p-3">Verify</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: for this purpose,better is to use wizards.instead of hiding and showing it,you can include those contents in wizards. check this link.it may help you. https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/eN4qy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example that shows one way to track the last div that a user clicked and then display it. It removes the div the user clicks, and then if you click on the 'Show Last Clicked Div' button, it will display the contents of the last clicked div below with a yellow background.

Here is a link to a JSFiddle so you can see it in action: [Show Last Div Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dayun123/e14qouwn/). This doesn't use jQuery, but you could convert it if need be.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">

    .btn-wrapper {
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 300px;
    }

    #div-container, #show-container {
      width: 800px;
    }

    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }

    .last-clicked {
      background: #FFFCAA;
    }

  </style>
</head>

  <body>

    <div id="div-container">

      <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <p>I'm some text in the first div</p>
        <button type="button" name="btn-1">Click Me 1</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <p>I'm some text in the second div</p>
        <button type="button" name="btn-2">Click Me 2</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <p>I'm some text in the third div</p>
        <button type="button" name="btn-3">Click Me 3</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="show-container">
      <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <button type="button" name="show">Show Last Clicked Div</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="last-clicked-container" class="hidden">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var previousDivClicked;

var divContainer = document.getElementById('div-container');
var showContainer = document.getElementById('show-container');
var lastClickedContainer = document.getElementById('last-clicked-container');

divContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  if (!lastClickedContainer.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    lastClickedContainer.classList.add('hidden');
  }

  if (e.target.getAttribute('type') === 'button') {
    previousDivClicked = e.target.parentElement
    console.log(previousDivClicked);
  }

  divContainer.removeChild(previousDivClicked);

});

showContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  lastClickedContainer.innerHTML = '';
  lastClickedContainer.classList.remove('hidden');
  previousDivClicked.classList.add('last-clicked');
  lastClickedContainer.appendChild(previousDivClicked);
});
```

Here's a brief explanation of what's going on:

**Code Explanation**

In the HTML, we have 3 divs that hold buttons that when clicked, will hide the divs:

```
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <p>I'm some text in the first div</p>
  <button type="button" name="btn-1">Click Me 1</button>
</div>

<!-- and so on... -->
```

We also have a div that holds the button that will show the last clicked div:

```
<div id="show-container">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button type="button" name="show">Show Last Clicked Div</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a div that is hidden where we can display the last clicked div:

```
<div id="last-clicked-container" class="hidden">

</div>
```

In the JS file, we grab the div container that holds all of the buttons that when clicked, hide their associated div, and we add an event listener for the 'click' event to it:

```
// selected at the beginning of the file, shown here for reference
var divContainer = document.getElementById('div-container');

divContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // rest of function after
```

We want to hide the div that was clicked only if the target of the event (the 'e' param) was a button. To get the div that was clicked from the button, we use the parentElement property since the button is the child of the div with the '.btn-wrapper' class:

```
if (e.target.getAttribute('type') === 'button') {
  previousDivClicked = e.target.parentElement
}
```

Above, we use the global previousDivClicked variable to store a reference to the div that the button (e.target) belonged to, so that we can display this div if necessary.

We then remove the entire div from the div container:

```
divContainer.removeChild(previousDivClicked);
```

That takes care of hiding the div that the button click came from and storing a reference to it for later use. Now, when we want to show the last div that was hidden, we do so by adding another event handler, this time on the 'click' event of the show container, which contains the button with the text 'Show Last Clicked Div':

```
// done at top of script but shown for reference
var showContainer = document.getElementById('show-container');

showContainer.addEventListener('click', function() { // rest of the function follows
```

In this function, we want to show the lastClickedContainer by removing the CSS '.hidden' class, and erase any content that was in the container previously:

```
lastClickedContainer.innerHTML = '';
lastClickedContainer.classList.remove('hidden');
```

Finally, we add a little CSS styling to the previousClickedDiv, then append it to the showContainer so it shows up on the page:

```
previousDivClicked.classList.add('last-clicked');
lastClickedContainer.appendChild(previousDivClicked);
```

Comment: Thank You so much! It's not exact but I found a way to implement using your logic

Answer (score 0):

If you want step form using jQuery then you can use below link.It will help you make steps as per your need and you do not needed that custom logic for that as well.Link is given below.Thank you.

[jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples)